# How to select the string names which has a more than 5 character

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, dictionary

I am trying to get the names (first) which has a longer than 5 letter but I could not make it

```
const fullNames = [
  { first: "Albus", last: "Dumbledore" },
  { first: "Harry", last: "Potter" },
  { first: "Hermione", last: "Granger" },
  { first: "Ron", last: "Weasley" },
  { first: "Rubeus", last: "Hagrid" },
  { first: "Minerva", last: "McGonagall" },
  { first: "Severus", last: "Snape" },];
```

```
const firstNames = fullNames.map(function (arg) {
  return arg.first.lenght >4;
});
```

Comment: Javascript.......

Comment: You spelled length incorrectly as "lenght".

Comment: Omg since this morning, I have been looking this :) Thank you so much

Comment: Just takes a second set of eyes sometimes.

Comment: What does the OP [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) expect to do? Going through an array and e.g. _"... trying to get the names (first) which has a longer than 5 letter ..."_ sounds more like a [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply achieve this requirement with the help of [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method as `Array.map()` will return the same number of elements you passed as a input.

Live Demo **:**

```js
const fullNames = [
  { first: "Albus", last: "Dumbledore" },
  { first: "Harry", last: "Potter" },
  { first: "Hermione", last: "Granger" },
  { first: "Ron", last: "Weasley" },
  { first: "Rubeus", last: "Hagrid" },
  { first: "Minerva", last: "McGonagall" },
  { first: "Severus", last: "Snape" }
];

const res = fullNames.filter(({ first }) => first.length > 5).map(({ first}) => first);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: @TahaYasin Can you please accept this answer if it helps so that it will be helpful for other fellow developers as well.